# jQuery datepicker, custom range quirk

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using jQuery datepicker, with a custom set of date ranges collected from a MySQL db. The resulting code from the query looks like this:

```
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
    var ranges = [ { start: new Date(2012, 02, 14), end: new Date(2012, 03, 31) } ];            
    $(function() {    
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
                    if(date >= ranges[i].start && date <= ranges[i].end) return [true, ''];
                }
                return [false, ''];
            },
            minDate: ranges[0].start,
            maxDate: ranges[ranges.length -1].end
        });
    });
});//]]>
```

(It is the date ranges that are queried).

My problem is this:

When the calendar is rendered, for some reason it decides to add a month onto what is selectable. Ie. if you set the end date as 31st March, it will change it to 1st May, or if you set it as !st Feb, it will allow you to select upto 1st March. I have tried getting around this by subtracting 1 month from the date, but of course this does not work as the months have different numbers of days, so if I had the 31st March in there, I could not simply minus 1 month as the 31st Feb does not exist.

Any ideas what is wrong with the code? I am pretty sure its the jQuery code above!

You can see the example at http://bookingtest.walesdesign.com

Comment: JavaScript `Date` uses 0-based month indices (which is stupid if you ask me)...January is 0, February is 1, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the problem is that you are setting the end date to 31st of april, which doesn't exists (and so the 1st of May is returned). **Remember  that months go from 0 (January) to 11 (December).** This works as expected from 14 February to 28 march

```
var ranges = [ { start: new Date(2012, 1, 14), end: new Date(2012, 2, 28) } ];             
$(function() {    
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: 'd MM, yy',
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            for(var i=0; i<ranges.length; i++) {
                if(date >= ranges[i].start && date <= ranges[i].end) return [true, ''];
            }
            return [false, ''];
        },
        minDate: ranges[0].start,
        maxDate: ranges[ranges.length -1].end
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! I didn't realise that months go from 0-11. So am I right in thinking I need to find a way to translate the PHP version of the date (where May = 5) to the jQuery version of the date (where May = 4). Is there a common way of doing this? Or do I just need to write a PHP script that will - 1 from the month?