# can datepicker mindate have two dates

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

```
$(tdForDatePicker).datepicker({
      numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
      dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
      defaultDate: myMinDateBegin,
      minDate: {date1:'01/03/2014', date2:'06/18/2014'},
      maxDate: {date1:'01/141/2014', date2: '06/30/2014'},
      onSelect: function () {
            $(this).focusin();                               
            }
      });
```

This is an example of what i am trying to do.  The user has two ranges to work with mindate: '01/03/2014' maxdate: '01/14/2014' and mindate: '06/18/2014' with maxdate: of '06/30/2014'.  multiDatesPicker does not work as I want in this part of my app.  How can I make datepicker to give user two mindate and two maxdate options.  My search in stackoverflow has not found this unique functionality.

Update:  Found this solution on [jQuery datepicker, custom range quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685151/jquery-datepicker-custom-range-quirk/9687028#9687028)

This is my present code:

```
ranges = [{ start: moment(new Date('01/03/2014')).format("MM/DD/YYYY"), end: moment(new Date('01/14/2014')).format("MM/DD/YYYY") },
               { start: moment(new Date('06/18/2014')).format("MM/DD/YYYY"), end: moment(new Date('06/30/2014')).format("MM/DD/YYYY") }];
    myMinDateBegin = ranges[0].start;
    myMaxDateBegin = ranges[ranges.length - 1].end;
    console.log('minDateBeginOnEdit', myMinDateBegin + " " + myMaxDateBegin);
    $(tdForDatePicker).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: [1, 1],
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            $.each(ranges, function (index) {
                    if(date >= ranges[index].start && date <= ranges[index].end){
                        return [true, ''];
                    }
                })
                return [false, ''];
            },
        minDate: myMinDateBegin,
        maxDate: myMaxDateBegin,          
        defaultDate: myMinDateBegin,
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).focusin();                               
        }
    })
```

The console reveals dates as 01/03/2014 and 06/30/2014.  The datepicker has all dates greyed out.

Comment: I have tried putting dates in an array: ['01/03/2014', '06/18/2014'] "datepicker cannot getTime" and if I put them in a string myTestMin = "'01/03/2014', '06/18/2014'" the datepicker gives me march 2027

Comment: minDate: '01/03/2014' || '06/17/2014' maxDate: '01/14/2014' || '06/30/2014' shows first range if I use && it shows last range.

Comment: took moment out of ranges. and now it go into the if statement.  I have done return [true, 'date'], and return [true, date].  which does not return anything.  minDate and maxDate seem to be working just no ranges yet.

Answer (score 1):

This holds the solution [jQuery ui: multiple ranges for date picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502073/jquery-ui-multiple-ranges-for-date-picker/3502183#3502183)

My Code

```
 var beGdate1start = new Date('01/03/2014');
    var beGdate1end = new Date('01/14/2014');
    var beGdate2start = new Date('06/18/2014');
    var beGdate2end = new Date('06/30/2014');
    $(tdForDatePicker).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            return [(date >= beGdate1start && date <= beGdate1end || date >= beGdate2start && date <= beGdate2end), ''];

            },            
        minDate: beGdate1start,
        maxDate: beGdate2end,
        //defaultDate: ranges[0].start,
        onSelect: function () {
            $(this).focusin();                               
        }
    })
```

The link gives a fiddle to play with.  Thanks.